# How to use a file from current directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am currently trying to pass a file name to one of the option parameters.
It works file when I use the full path/description of the file.

```
options["fName"] = "<FULL PATH.../test.apk>";
```

However, is there a way to take the file from the current directory like

```
options["fName"] = "test.apk";
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
options["fName"] = "./test.apk";
```

Comment: gives me the error: "Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Bad argument"

Comment: sorry not a meteor guy .. what about options["fName"] = process.cwd() + '/test.apk';

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
var dir = process.env.PWD;
options["fName"] = "./test.apk";
```

Comment: Be careful when using relative paths like that. If you use any var path = require('path') methods it typically returns paths without the relative attribute. When dealing with files I would recommend using the included path module.

Answer (score 0):

`options.fName = __dirname+'/test.apk';`